German Job Seeker Visa to Work Permit appointment
I came to Germany on a job seeker visa and secured a job offer. They wanted me to start in two weeks but the visa conversion appointment is available only in December. The immigration office says I can work as it is delayed from their side but my employer is refusing to accept. How can I get an appointment in the next week?

The immigration office may issue you a so-called Fiktionsbescheinigung to document that your application is pending. This paper may explicitly permit work. With that, you have no work permit, but as long as the document is valid you can start working. So more than a "the office says," it is a "the office writes." An employer might still dislike hiring you because of the risk that the permit might not be granted in the end.
